# ImportError: cannot import name 'structures' python music library

Tags: python, jython, jython-music

I'm trying to play a note, however, importing music python library is giving me a headache

[image]

```
from music import *

note = Note(C4, HN)
Play.midi(note)
```

I also tried

```
import music

note = Note(C4, HN)
Play.midi(note)
```

Still got the same error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-1cac5ec470ec> in <module>()
----> 1 import music
      2 
      3 note = Note(C4, HN)
      4 Play.midi(note)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/music/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from .utils import H
----> 2 from . import utils, tables, synths, effects, structures, singing
      3 from . import legacy
      4 

ImportError: cannot import name 'structures'
```

Comment: It doesn't matter so much with an error message, but its best to post all code and errors as actual text rather than images.

Comment: I edited the question and included the exact error message. Those were the only lines, 3 lines of code and then, the error message.

Comment: Try to upgrade module misic: `pip install music --upgrade`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to run the examples in IPython, which does not support JythonMusic.

You need to download the JythonMusic environment (JEM) which comes bundled with everything.  See here -

http://jythonmusic.org/download/